# Mapplotlib Output Issue

Tags: python

So I am working on a project for school and at a complete facedesking loss here.  My dictionaries are in order and I am converting the numerical values to a float as I should, but when Mapplot renders it the numbers come out in a an alphabetical order (ie: 1111, 1112, 133333, 20) on the graph.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix it and it's got me frustrated.

I am wanting to have the values displayed in a proper numeric order (descending) and cannot get it to work.

```
import sqlite3
import re
import requests
from math import pi
from itertools import chain
from collections import namedtuple
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, FuncTickFormatter, FixedTicker, ColumnDataSource
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import OrderedDict
from pandas import DataFrame
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

token = ''
header = headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}','Content-type': 'application/json'}

steam_hours = requests.get('https://query.data.world/s/5cOVc-nvDK4DkUJ2MFZuAqCcAqTJrN', 
                             headers=headers)
raw_data = steam_hours.text

steam_list = raw_data.split('\r\n')
#print(steam_list)
steam_list[2]



game_hours = [r.split('|')[-1] for r in steam_list[1:]]
game_name = [r.split('|')[0] for r in steam_list[1:]]

game_hours_edit = [i.replace('"', '') for i in game_hours]

def remove_comma(s):
    return s[1:]

def remove_comma_name(s):
    return s[:-1]



game_hours_edit = [remove_comma(s) for s in game_hours_edit]
game_hours = game_hours_edit

game_name_edit = [remove_comma_name(s) for s in game_name]
game_name = game_name_edit

games_dict = OrderedDict(zip(game_name, game_hours))
print(games_dict)

#key, value = ('asd', 1)

print('\n')
for key, value in games_dict.items():
    print('\n')
    print(key, value)
print('\n')


scrubbed = [re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', game_hours) for game_hours in game_hours]
#print(f"Game Name: {game_name}\n Hours Played: {scrubbed}")

conn = sqlite3.connect('steam_hours.db')
cur = conn.cursor() 
cur.execute('''drop table IF EXISTS name_game''')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name_game (game_name TEXT, game_hours TEXT)''')

for key, value in games_dict.items():
    #print(game_name)
    #print(game_hours)
    cur.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO name_game VALUES (?, ?)', (key, value,))
    conn.commit()

name_results = cur.execute('SELECT game_name FROM name_game LIMIT 10;').fetchall()
hours_results = cur.execute('SELECT game_hours FROM name_game DESC LIMIT 10;').fetchall()


all_compiled = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from name_game", conn)
name_compiled = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT game_name from name_game", conn)
hours_compiled = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT game_hours from name_game", conn)




names_flat = [item for sublist in name_results for item in sublist]
hours_flat = [item for sublist in hours_results for item in sublist]

list_int = np.array(hours_flat)

print(list_int)

names_reversed = names_flat[::-1]
hours_reversed = hours_flat[::-1]

from collections import OrderedDict

final_dict = OrderedDict(zip(list_int, names_flat ))

print("final dict")
print(final_dict)

print("FOR LOOP")
print('\n')
for key, value in final_dict.items():
    print('\n')
    print(key, value)
print('\n')

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('TOP 10 STEAM GAMES BY HOURS PLAYED', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
plt.xticks(rotation=15, fontsize=8)
bar_width = 2  # default: 0.8


plt.ylabel('Hours Played', fontsize=8)
plt.xlabel('Game Name', fontsize=8)
plt.bar(range(len(final_dict)), final_dict.keys(), align="center", width=.5)
plt.xticks(range(len(final_dict)),  list(final_dict.values()))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `int` on all of the numerical inputs? Strings are sorted lexicographically so you'd need to convert them to integers for it to work properly.

Comment: How would I go about that? Still new to Python.  And there are two things stored in the Dict.  One is a list of words the other is the number values.

Comment: If you have a problem with matplotlib please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve only related to the issue. No need for all the other stuff. Just add some example data that has the same format as what you expect.